# C# Bingo Algorithm for Checking BIngo

Tags: c#

I have a 5x5 2D array of type Boolean and I want to check for vertical, horizontal, and diagonal bingo.

If values at those specific cells are set to "true", I get a bingo. Otherwise, I continue to play the game. I was looking for help to improve, or get feedback to completely re-haul this method for checking for a Bingo.

```cs
public int checkForBingo(int rowID, int colID) 
{    
    bool winner = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        //checking verts and horiz
        if (winner = (boardState[i, 0]) == true && (boardState[i, 1] == true)
            && (boardState[i, 2] == true) && (boardState[i, 3] == true)
              && (boardState[i, 4] == true))
            break;
        else if (winner = (boardState[0, i] == true) && (boardState[1, i] == true)
            && (boardState[2, i] == true) && (boardState[3, i] == true) &&
            (boardState[4, i] == true))
            break;

        //checking diagonals
        if (!winner)
        {
            if (boardState[2, 2] == true)
                if ((winner = (boardState[0, 0] == true) && (boardState[1, 1] == true) &&
                    (boardState[3, 3] == true) && (boardState[4, 4] == true)))
                    break;
                else if (!(winner = (boardState[0, 4] == true) && (boardState[1, 3] == true) &&
                        (boardState[3, 1] == true) && (boardState[4, 0] == true)))
                    break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is really hard to read - assignments in the `if` ? Almost a side effect - very easy to miss if you aren't careful. Why not 2 loops: 1 row 0..4 and 1 col 0..4 - at least `row` and `col` are better names than `i`. Also for `i < 4` in a 5x5 array ?

Comment: I think this questions is more fitting for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. As far as code review goes, Alex's answer seems to cover most of the points. My main issue with the code other than what was already mentioned is that it's not easily modifiable. What if you want to switch to a 10x10 board? There are many magic numbers that you have to surgically replace in order to achieve that or any type of change

Answer (score 1):

For loop run from i=0 to 3
That means it's checking 4 rows only and in if condition you are checking for all 5 columns which is right.
Change your for loop condition to

```
i <= 4
```

Answer (score 1):

A few thing to note:

- The main for loop should go be `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` less
  than 5 ( arrays are 0 based)
- You dont need to check for == true, a boolean value can be simple
  encapsulated in a if statement such as:

  if (boardState[0, 4] && boardState[1, 3] && boardState[3, 1] && boardState[4, 0])
- The assignment in the `if` could lead to unwanted behavior(side
  effects) easy to forget is there.
- The method signature should be capitalized ergo `CheckForBingo`
- If you are not using the parameters - then remove them from the method
  signature
- As noted the code is a bit hard to follow

For comparison and learning purpose(myself included) I have written the method like this:

```
public bool CheckForBingo(bool[,] boardState)
        {
            bool haveWeWon = false;

            //check horizotal
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                haveWeWon = true;

                for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
                {
                    if (!boardState[i, y])
                    {
                        haveWeWon = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(haveWeWon)
                {
                    return haveWeWon;
                }
            }

            if (!haveWeWon)
            {
                //check vertical
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    haveWeWon = true;

                    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
                    {
                        if (boardState[y, i])
                        {
                            haveWeWon = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (haveWeWon)
                    {
                        return haveWeWon;
                    }
                }
            }

            //check the middle - if false dont bother checking diagonal
            if (boardState[2, 2])
            {
                if (!haveWeWon)
                {
                    //check top left diagonal 
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        haveWeWon = true;

                        if (!boardState[i, i])
                        {
                            haveWeWon = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (haveWeWon)
                    {
                        return haveWeWon;
                    }
                }

                if (!haveWeWon)
                {
                    //check top right diagonal 
                    for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        haveWeWon = true;

                        if (!boardState[i, i])
                        {
                            haveWeWon = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (haveWeWon)
                    {
                        return haveWeWon;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```